# Determined the number of different letter permutation, of any length, that can be made using the letters LOTTO.

Tags: combinatorics

If I had one repeated letter I would have approached using the explanation here
[How many "words" of any length can be made from the letters in TREATS?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517480/how-many-words-of-any-length-can-be-made-from-the-letters-in-treats)
but it has two repeated words, and seems like I am doing double counting in my calculation. Can anyone suggest how to approach here in this problem.

Comment: What number did you get?

Comment: I used this in calculation $\frac{{5!}}{{2! \times 2!}} + \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^3 {{{\left( 3 \right)}_i} + 2 \times \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^3 {{{\left( 3 \right)}_i}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{i + 2}\\
2
\end{array}} \right)} } $

Comment: The 1st term considering all the letters, 2nd term considering 3 distinct letters, and 3rd term for 4 letter word considering "O" repeated twice and then "T" repeated twice. I don't think I am doing it right when I am considering 4 letter word and that's where I am confused.

Comment: In the summation k is actually i. Typo mistake.

Comment: Answer that I am getting is 155.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An admissible word can have $i\in\{0,1\}$ Ls, $j\in\{0,1,2\}$ Os, and $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ Ts. Let $J$ be the set of admissible triples $(i,j,k)$. When such a triple has been selected the $i+j+k$  resulting letters L, O, T can be permuted in
$${(i+j+k)!\over i!\>j!\>k!}$$
ways. It follows that the number $N$ of admissible words is given by
$$N=\sum_{(i,j,k)\in J}{(i+j+k)!\over i!\>j!\>k!}=90\ .$$
This of course includes the empty word.

(Instead of $\sum_{(i,j,k)\in J}$ you could write $\sum_{i=0}^1\sum_{j=0}^2\sum_{k=0}^2\ $. There are $2\cdot3\cdot3=18$ terms in all.)

Comment: Trying to understand the solution along with the explanation link put in the question description. I am trying to understand the summation, and the value which came as 90. I have never come across/worked with such summation :-(